# 403 Forbidden error for kubernetes for drupal+postgresql

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, drupal, http-status-code-403

Working in GCP to host drupal with PostgreSQL
Here are my resources:
[image]

I'm trying to enter into my external IP to view the portal but getting a 403 Forbidden error. like this:
[image]

I tried `kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-anonymous --clusterrole=cluster-admincl --user=system:anonymous` command to config role but its not working. I'm just learning these things as a student i do not understand how these things works.
Could anyone please help me also with a brief explanation how its not working and whats causing it?

Postgres-deploy file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/lib/postgres"
              subPath: "postgres"
              name: postgres-data
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-secrets
                  key: USER_NAME       
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-secrets
                  key: ROOT_PASSWORD
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: task-pv-claim
```

Answer (score 0):

If this 403 error might be due to drupal installation , Please Remove the following lines from the .htaccess file and check whether the issue is resolved. If it still persists  find this doc to resolve the [403 error](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted)

Remove the following lines from the .htaccess file :

Options -Indexes

Options FollowSymLinks-

[403 Forbidden error with Drupal after install](https://my.ultrawebhosting.com/knowledgebase/184/403-Forbidden-error-with-Drupal-after-install.html)